# Azure: Error 503: Service Unavailable After Switching App Service Plan For An App Service in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-apps, azure-diagnostics, azure-app-service-plans

Initially I had two app services (API App 1 and API App 2) consuming single App Service Plan A, I switched the App Service Plan for one of the app services (API App 2) to another App Service Plan B.

I had taken care of the pre-requisites as mentioned on the Azure Microsoft Documentation as follows:

1. The new App Service Plan B must have same location as that of old
   i.e share same webspace.
2. The new App Service Plan B must be part of the same Resource Group
   in Azure

Also both App Service Plans A and B have same Pricing Tier.
After I had switched the Plan A to Plan B for API App 2 since then it's giving Service unavailable Error 503 earlier I could browse the service and it was working perfectly fine.

Can someone please suggest as what I could have missed?
The App Service Plan B was shown in App Service Selector blade by default once I chose to switch the App Service Plan.

What I have already tried:

1. Restarting of App Service many times - No effect
2. Generating Reports to diagnose problem - Insights shared below
3. Reverting the changes back - No effect

Even after I switched the App Service back to it's original app service plan I am getting same error.

To diagnose this problem I have already looked into App Insights and App Error Analysis. I generated two reports which gave following insights:

- High CPU Usage detected on only one instance in your app service
  plan.
- Site/App crashed due to unknown reasons
- App is experiencing server errors
- Requests time outs.
- Page Operations: Azure detected moderately high levels of Page
  Reads/sec on one instance in your app service plan. The highest value
  was [number]'170.673073344018',which is close to a level that would
  cause serious problems for that instance.
- Your application was recycled as the Azure scale unit was undergoing
  an upgrade. There are periodic updates made by Microsoft to the
  underlying Azure platform to improve overall reliability,
  performance, and security of the platform infrastructure where your
  application is running on.Most of these updates are performed without
  any impact upon your web app. To reduce the impact of such events on
  your application, consider deploying your application to multiple
  regions and use Azure Traffic Manager to distribute the load across
  regions.

The app was working perfectly fine just before I switched the App Plans, I have no idea what might have went wrong.  If there's some downtime when we change the App Service Plan then approx. how much time it is?  Is there something else that needs to be updated once we switch the service plan?  Does the affected instance that had peak usage needs to be repaired somehow?  Will migrating API APP to new Azure App Service Plan C work?

Comment: Have you changed to a new service plan or existing?

Comment: I had switched the api app between the pre-existing app service plans from Plan A to Plan B only. After error I switched back to original Plan A but same error is shown on browsing service.

Comment: My problem was solved after creating new app service plan and API app , hence I moved the code to the new API app. I deleted the old API App and Service Plan